# Adding fragments in GraphQL query from Java

Tags: java, graphql

After long hours session of finding any documentation, I am forced to ask the community.

Currently the query I am making from Java code(also tried the same with Postman) to query GraphQL:

**Request:**

```
{"query":"{findPublisherByLicenseNumber(licenseNumber : \"UAE_DXB_CMH-971\") {name licenseNumber}}"}
```

**Response:**

```
{
    "data": {
        "findPublisherByLicenseNumber": {
            "name": "Cantaloupe Media House",
            "licenseNumber": "UAE_DXB_CMH-971"
        }
    }
}
```

This is the query which I have made in my backend to query endpoint: `http://mg-api.com/mg-graphQL`

As of now I have mentioned two fields only but actual Schema has many.

```
type Publisher {
    ID: ID!
    name: String!
    licenseNumber: String!
    address: String
    contactNumber: String
    mobileNumber: String
    areaCode: Int!
    ...
    ... #few more fields
    books: [Book]

}

extend type Query {
    findAllPublishers: [Publisher]!
    findPublisherByLicenseNumber(licenseNumber: String!) : Publisher!

}
```

The fragment that I want to add in Query:

```
fragment publisherInfo on Publisher {
    ID
    name
    licenseNumber
    address
    contactNumber
    areaCode
}
```

Tried like this

```
{"query":"{findPublisherByLicenseNumber(licenseNumber : \"UAE_DXB_CMH-971\") {...publisherInfo}}", "fragment" : "fragment publisherInfo on Publisher {ID name licenseNumber address contactNumber areaCode }"}
```

but got **`ValidationError`** with `message` : **`Undefined fragment publisherInfo`**.

```
{
    "data": null,
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Validation error of type UndefinedFragment: Undefined fragment pubInfo @ 'findPublisherByLicenseNumber'",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 1,
                    "column": 67,
                    "sourceName": null
                }
            ],
            "description": "Undefined fragment pubInfo",
            "validationErrorType": "UndefinedFragment",
            "queryPath": [
                "findPublisherByLicenseNumber"
            ],
            "errorType": "ValidationError",
            "path": null,
            "extensions": null
        }
    ]
}
```

When I try to achieve the same with **`GraphiQL`** UI then it works.

I have not started to look to call this from UI Frameworks where I need to use graphql.js in Vanilla JS/Angular/React/Vue etc.

As of now I am looking to utilize this from my backend code logic as there is a middleware between UI and my graphql service.

The only thing I found was left unanswered and if answered then totally in vague manner : [S.O Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46697150/graphql-fragment-json-format)

Any help is appreciated.

**SOLVED**

Need to pass fragment before method;

```
{"query":"fragment pubInfo on Publisher {name licenseNumber contactNumber} {findPublisherByLicenseNumber(licenseNumber :\"UAE_DXB_CMH-971\") {...pubInfo}}"}
```

Answer (score -1):

**SOLVED**

Need to pass fragment before/after method call body `{}` in the same **Query**;

```
{"query":"fragment pubInfo on Publisher {name licenseNumber contactNumber} {findPublisherByLicenseNumber(licenseNumber :\"UAE_DXB_CMH-971\") {...pubInfo}}"}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, the position of the fragment is *not* important. It can be placed before or after the operation.